Express.js Mongoose Update Route Not Receiving Request Body Data from Axios PUT Request
Currently a beginner in backend programming and just following tutorials in YouTube and have successfully made coded a post and get endpoint but currently I am stuck when it comes to editing the data. The problem appears to be that the server-side route handling the PUT request is not receiving the expected request body data from the Axios PUT request sent by the client. Despite the client sending the data in the request body using FormData, the server logs indicate that the request body is empty when received.
Client Side-Code
'use client';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

const EditRecruitModal = ({ recruit, onClose, recruitId }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(recruit.recruitFullName || '');
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(recruit.desiredProfession || '');
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(recruit.recruitmentStatus || '');
    const [contact, setContact] = useState(recruit.recruitContactInfo || '');
    const [picture, setPicture] = useState(null);
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      setName(recruit.recruitFullName || '');
      setPosition(recruit.desiredProfession || '');
      setStatus(recruit.recruitmentStatus || '');
      setContact(recruit.recruitContactInfo || '');
    }, [recruit]);
  
    const submitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        console.log('Submitting form...');
        
        console.log('Name:', name);
        console.log('Position:', position);
        console.log('Status:', status);
        console.log('Contact:', contact);
        console.log('Picture:', picture);
        console.log('File:', file);
    
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', name);
        formData.append('position', position);
        formData.append('status', status);
        formData.append('contact', contact);
        if (picture) {
            formData.append('picture', picture);
        }
        if (file) {
            formData.append('file', file);
        }
        console.log( name, position, status, contact)
    
        for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
        }
        
        
        try {
            const response = await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/recruit/${recruitId}`, formData, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            });
            console.log('Recruit updated:', response.data);
            onClose();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating recruit:', error);
        }

Server Side Code
const express = require("express")
const server = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
server.use(express.json())
const cors = require('cors')

//Update
server.put('/recruit/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;

        console.log("Received PUT request for recruit with ID:", id);

        console.log("Request body:", req.body);

        const updatedRecruit = await recruit.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, { new: true });

        console.log("Updated recruit:", updatedRecruit);

        if (!updatedRecruit) {
            console.log("Recruit not found");
            return res.status(404).json({ message: "Not Found" });
        }

        console.log("Recruit updated successfully");

        res.status(200).json(updatedRecruit);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error updating recruit:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
})

I have consoled log everything in the Client Side Code and everything is okay. It stores the new value and retains the values that weren't changed, including file and image paths. But when it I console out response.data, it shows that none of the values has changed. I checked the server side and added console logs and found out that the req.body is empty.

You need specific middleware like Multer to handle multipart/form-data requests. What middleware are you using?

Does this answer your question? Node/Express file upload

Also see this answer, you should not manually set the content-type request header when sending FormData from the browser

Yea, I'm using Multer as a middleware, my bad for not including that and yes it works now thanks!
